# Intellij Idea Error creating a class

Tags: intellij-idea, google-drive-api

I've been trying to create a new class in Idea but I keep getting this error:

[image]

this project is not under any Version control but I've tried to change settings in the version control anyways and it didn't work.

Comment: Judging by the URL, you're trying to edit code in a directory synchronized with Google Drive. Do you have write access to the corresponding directory in Google Drive?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to check that, I didn't even know that you needed to have that in order to work with files on my computer even if they're synced with GoogleDrive. BTW the app is off now.

Comment: Can you create files in that directory using another tool (Notepad for example)?

Comment: Yes... I can. just tried it with notepad

Comment: If you turn off the 'Use "safe write"' option in Settings | General (Settings | Appearance and Behavior | System settings in IJ 14), does it help?

Comment: yole, No, still doesn't work....

Comment: Now, I found on the keymap there's a shortcut to turn off read only.

Comment: There is, but it applies only to files. Could you please open the IntelliJ IDEA log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) and see if there are any exceptions there?

Comment: when I tried that, I keep getting an error "Failed to change read-only flag"

Comment: 2014-12-20 20:05:24,338 [ 381057]   INFO - es.ui.CreateFromTemplateDialog - Cannot modify a read-only directory 'D:\GoogleDrive\TAU\3rd Semester\Software 1\Workspace\HW8\src'. 
com.intellij.util.IncorrectOperationException: Cannot modify a read-only directory 'D:\GoogleDrive\TAU\3rd Semester\Software 1\Workspace\HW8\src'.

Comment: Okay... so it's happening because it's in the Google Drive folder. just opened a project somewhere else and it works fine. any ideas?